# Sign-in out clearing the session data

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller, session-state

I have this link to Logout. How can I logout clearing my session
The current session needs to be cleared/abandoned when user clicks sign out. Then direct user to the log in page(a URL is given ex., login.com)

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#">Sign Out</a>
```

Never worked on session. How can I proceed further?

Comment: Are you trying to auto-logout based on time also the session needs to be cleared and it should redirect the current user to the login page?

Comment: No, auto logout based on time. But Yes,  session needs to be cleared and it should redirect the current user to the login page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try implementing Session.Abandon() Method.

> Session.Abandon();

```
public ActionResult LogOut()
{
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.Abandon(); 
    return RedirectToAction("index", "login");
}
```

For Session Timeout, check this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525473(v=vs.90)

For Session Abanden Method, check this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524310(v=vs.90)

For HttpSessionState Method, check this - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate_members.aspx

Comment: I need to add onclick= LogOut() method in <a href> ?

Comment: @Ben Yes, you have to. In that method, you need to implement Session.Abandon(); in the logic code.